# Java replaceAll throwing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java

I faced Null Pointer Exception while using replaceAll API of String class.

then I tried with small snippet pasted below, I am getting NPE.

```
    String s = "HELLO @WORLD@ I AM.";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("@WORLD@", null)) ;
```

I also, found that in String.java class

```
  public Matcher appendReplacement(StringBuffer sb, String replacement) {
        .......//code

        while (cursor < replacement.length()) { ..//code}
        .......//code
}
```

So here it calls `replacement.length()` which is cause of NPE.

is there rule that we can't pass second argument as null?

I am aware that what JVM will replace if your replacing word is null.

Comment: Immediate question is  What is your desired output ?

Comment: When you pass a null value to an API method that you have no control over NPE is a very probable output.... What exactly did you expect?

Comment: I faced this at runtime as first time the value at replacing end as NULL, I thought it will keep empty value at replacing place by itself. I knew the solution is to keep "" instead of NULL, but again now I need to have check before calling this function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

replace string with empty string rather then null. `s.replaceAll("@WORLD@", ""
)`

Comment: Assuming output as "Hello  I AM"

Answer (score 2):

You can see [null jls-4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html)

```
s.replaceAll("@WORLD@", null); //NPE
```

What is null?

```
The null type has one value, the null reference, represented by the null literal null. 
It is nothing.
```

[replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) second argument is String which can not be `null` because `null` is nothing

```
 public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
                                          ↑
```

So, you have to correct the call

```
s.replaceAll("@WORLD@", ""); // "" empty String
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass null here, as while replacing, `Matcher` class try to check the length of new word to replace char by char. You can put "null" if you want to see in your string.